# am using this for Query String to filter the Movies I have in the database there's something wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

string mid = Request.QueryString["ID"];

```
    if ( db.Movies.Where(i=>i.ID==mid))
    {
        repMovie.DataSource = db.Movies.Find().ToString();

        repMovie.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: .Where doesn't return a boolean

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.Any()` to return a boolean in your if statement.

`Any()` returns true if any results are returned by an enumerable object.

```
if ( db.Movies.Where(i=>i.ID==mid).Any()) 
{    
    //...
}
```

Comment: Could even simplify to just use Any like `db.Movies.Any(i => i.ID == mid)`

Answer (score 1):

First, `db.Movies.Where(i=>i.ID==mid)` isn't a boolean. Why are you testing if it's true or false?

Second, `repMovie.DataSource = db.Movies.Find().ToString();` has no condition on it. How will that return the right thing? Why don't you do this instead:

(Assuming there's going to be a maximum of one match, ever):

```
var matchingMovie = db.Movies.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == movieId);
if (matchingMovie !== null) {
   // you found it in one operation and can work with it now
}
```

I recommend against variable names like `mid`. What's that? Anyone else who sees it, or even yourself in a few months, will have no idea and will have to do extra scanning work to figure out its meaning. Use `movieId` instead.

And for that matter, why are you getting the movieId directly from the querystring yourself? Your MVC action methods should do this for you:

```
public ActionResult Index(int ID) {
   // Lookie! you've automatically gotten the ID from the querystring, and
   // you also know it's a non-null integer. If it were null or a non-integer,
   // it wouldn't match this route and the client would get a 404, unless you
   // had another route to handle those.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate ways

```
int numMid = Convert.ToInt32(mid);
if ( db.Movies.Where(i=>i.ID==numMid).Count()>0) 
{    
    //...
}
```

or

```
int numMid = Convert.ToInt32(mid);
if (db.Movies.Any(i=>i.ID==numMid)) 
{    
    //...
}
```

Comment: it gives me a error                                                                                                 CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

Comment: I have updated the above code, You have to convert the String var to Int before comparing.

Comment: Doing a `Where` followed by a `Count > 0` is a horribly non-performing way to do the job. If all you need to know if there's one, you do `First` or `Take(1)`!